# Check if list of objects already exists in another list of objects

Tags: c#

1- I
I load list of Persons from CSV file and store it in list
I load also list of Persons from db and store it in List

how can i get the users which they are in the csv file but not in the databse?

> For example: DB has 5 Users (A,B,C,D,E) , CSV has 4 users (B,E,Q,P)
>   the code should return list of users (Q,P)

```
public class Person
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}



 public class App
        {
            private IEnumerable<Person> usersDb;
            private IEnumerable<Person> usersCsv;

            public App(int age)
        {
             usersDb = GetUsersFromDb(age);
             usersCsv = GetUsersFromCsv(age);
        }

        public void AddMissingUsers()
        {
            var missingUsers = usersCsv.Where(x => !usersDb.Any(y => x.UserName.Trim().ToUpper().
                Equals(y.UserName.Trim().ToUpper()))); //I tried this one 
            // add to database
        }

    }
```

**Additional question**

> Ps: I'm using entity framwork 6 is there a better way to perform the task shown in my code? instate of getting all users with from database then check if exists?
>
> In the other hand, if i do the opposite and check each row in my csv file if exists in databse, this is also can be long operation since the file can contain many rows.

Comment: What is wrong with your attempt? It doesn't look obviously wrong. Also, case sensitivity is usually defined in the database's collation, so you may not need to call `ToUpper` at all

Comment: You might also look into [`MERGE in SQL Server`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb510625.aspx) - which means you dump the new file into a temporary table, and merge the results (in this case, simply insert when not matched), then drop the temporary table. Very fast for large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use `Except` in this case.

```
 var usersNotInDb = usersCsv.Except(usersDb).ToList();
 context.Users.AddRange(usersNotInDb);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem,
Change your Person class as follows,

```
public class Person : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        bool IEqualityComparer<Person>.Equals(Person x, Person y)
        {
            if (x.UserName == y.UserName)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<Person>.GetHashCode(Person obj)
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then change your query to,

```
Person p = new Person();
        var notInDBList = usersCsv.Except(usersDb, p).ToList();
```